What is the correct description for this type of window latch?
Does this type of surface mounted window latch have a specific name or description.
It's a two part surface mounted latch, where one half is mounted on the window mullion or frame, and the other half is mounted on the sash?
Specifically, it does not involve cutting or recessing a component, just surface mounting.


You may get better answers of you showed additional views including just how this latch is intended to work.

I'm afraid I would just call it a surface mounted latch for a hinged window.

@Michael Karas, it's just a handle that pulls down over a peg. There is only one moving part.

No answers so far. I rest my case with my previous comment.

@Michael Karas, it may simply be that people don't know the answer.

I repeat myself then. Show some additional pictures so that folks who may be able to answer can get a much better idea of what you are asking about.  It would probably also help this question a lot if you could provide more background of just why you are asking this and what you need that information for.

@Michael Karas, this is seriously all that here is, it's just a handle that swings down over a catch. There's nothing more to it. I'm looking for the name so I know what to Google when I buy a new one.

I think the problem is that it doesn't have a generic name. It is simply one kind of mechanical latch.

@keshlam, it's a casement latch because it's a latch designed to fit on a casement window.

The answer is that these are "Casement" fixtures. Usually called a casement latch or a casement fastener. Occasionally a Casement handle.
The name is a reference to a "casement window", a windows that swings on vertically mounted hinges as a door would open. They are distinguished from other types of window latch in that one half of the mechanism is set into or mounted on what would be the door frame, were it a door.
